# Doing recursive deep through dependencies in ruby on rails npm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, npm

I have a small controller class to get dependencies of an NPM package. Which is giving me dependencies for a package when I do `/package/:package_anme/dependencies`. But I could only go to 1 level. or 2 level, How I can go to an infinite level of dependencies..

```
class DependenciesController < ApplicationController
  def package
    level_one_deps = parse_dependencies_for_package(fetch_dependencies_for_package(params[:package_name]))

    level_two_deps=
      level_one_deps.map do |dep|
        parse_dependencies_for_package(fetch_dependencies_for_package(dep))
      end

    level_two_clean_deps = reject_empty(level_two_deps).flatten

    render json: level_one_deps + level_two_clean_deps
  end

  private

  def fetch_dependencies_for_package(package)
    JSON.parse(Faraday.get("http://registry.npmjs.org/#{package}/latest").body)["dependencies"]
  end

  def parse_dependencies_for_package(dependencies)
    case dependencies
    when nil
      []
    else
      dependencies.map { |e| e[0] }
    end
  end

  def reject_empty(deps)
    deps.reject { |c| c.empty? }
  end
end
```

I want to get dependencies for each dependency until its end, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is recursive, therefore any solution is recursive.  You can set up your own stack and handle the recursion that way, but you're still doing it recursively.

Update:

Originally, the question was "how do I do this in a non-recursive manner?", which is why my answer is "you can't".  The question has changed, so let's have a new answer :)

When handling a recursive problem you must have a condition which ends the recursion.  For many problems you have a straight-forward tree that you're walking and when you reach a leaf you return the result.

This one is a bit different, though, which is why I'm answering it.  The problem here is that each branch might not have an end itself. Package x depends on package y which depends on package z.  Are they all so tidy?  Maybe package x depends on y and z, and y and z both depend on w.  This provides us with a glimpse of the solution because there's no reason to pull in w twice.

What I'd do is create a recursive function that takes a Hash as a parameter as well as a package name.  For each package, add it to the hash and then recurse.  If it's already in the hash, skip it.  That simple logic should do it.

Some code, which works with what you have above:

```
def get_deps(package, all_deps = Hash.new)
  return if all_deps[package]
  these_deps = parse_dependencies_for_package(fetch_dependencies_for_package(package))
  all_deps[package] = these_deps 
  these_deps.each { |dep| get_deps(dep, all_deps) }
  return all_deps
end
```